# Undergraduate mathematical magazines to improve mathematical knowledge

Tags: soft-question, big-list

I'm sorry my ignorance, I don't know very much about mathematical magazines. I'm finishing my master degree in pure mathematics and I'm looking for mathematical magazines which could improve my undergraduate mathematical knowledge and in the same time help me to review the undergraduate contents.

After years studying pure mathematics I miss something to put all this knowledge altogether to solve interesting problems as for example a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra using some basic analysis theorem or a simple proof using basic category theory of a known theorem in analysis or topology (undergraduate level). I would like something which can be read by an average mathematical bachelor (in pure mathematics).

I think this will enhance my mathematical creativity and see how mathematics can be beautiful.

**Remark:**

I found this magazine, I don't if it's what I'm looking for: http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/college-mathematics-journal-contents-january-2014

Anyway, are there another ones? can be in French, Spanish or English.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I enjoy browsing the Mathematical Monthly (also from the M.A.A., as it happens).

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [Math Horizons](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/math-horizons), although it might be a bit breezy if you're looking for more "serious" math that's still accessible to undergraduates.

Answer (score 2):

The AMS, american mathematical society has publications that are useful, eg "Notices of the American Mathematical Society"; there are others, [link here](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journals), there are a slew of journals at AMS, and could help. Also there is another publication "Girls' Angle", [link here](http://www.girlsangle.org/page/bulletin.php), this is a girls math education magazine and could serve as a good knowledge base for basic/undergraduate math base(for those with rusted math, or simply curious!).